# Gmaps4rails : Using Bootstrap modal with gmaps4rails infowindows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, gmaps4rails

I have managed to apply `gmaps4rails` in my application

**FIRST METHOD**

I have a **`map`** action like this:

```
def map
  @family = Family.all.to_gmaps4rails do |family,marker|
    marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/layouts/info", :locals => { :family => family})
  end
end
```

in my **_info.html.erb**:

```
<h5><%=family.location%></h5>

<%=link_to "View Details","#myModal",class: "btn btn-success",data: {toggle: "modal"} %>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel" style="color:#9D5641;margin-top:10px;">Family Details</h3>
        <h5>Family ID : <%=family.famid%></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <%= family.persons.count %>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Mobile No.</th>
                <th>Photo</th>
            </tr>
            <% family.persons.each do |person| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=person.name%></td>
                    <td><%=person.mobnum%></td>
                    <td><%=person.photo%></td>
                </tr>
            <%end%>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <h5><%=link_to "Veiw Full Details", {controller: :managedb ,action: :details, famid: family.famid} %></h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

The bootstrap's modal is rendered fine but with a glitch. It looks like this:

[image]

**The modal is supposed to be on top of the `grey` color layer**.

I guess this is happening **beacause** I'm rendering the `modal` in the `infowindow` partial. That is why it's css properties are that of the `infowindow`. How do I make it work as normal `modal`.

I can remove the `background-color` which we get once the modal is activated by adding:

> .modal-backdrop {background: none;}

to my css file.

But the **modal is not `clickable`. I cannot click on the links in it and so on.How to fix this?

**ALTERNATE METHOD I TRIED**

**map action**

```
    def map
        @family = Family.all.to_gmaps4rails do |family,marker|
            @fam=family
            marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/layouts/map", :locals => { :family => family})
        end
    end
```

**_info.html.erb**

```
<h5><%=family.location%></h5>

<%=link_to "View Details","#myModal",class: "btn btn-success",data: {toggle: "modal"} %>
```

**map.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <%= gmaps4rails(@family) %>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel" style="color:#9D5641;margin-top:10px;">Family Details</h3>
            <h5>Family ID : <%=@fam.famid%></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile No.</th>
                    <th>Photo</th>
                </tr>
                <% @fam.persons.each do |person| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%=person.name%></td>
                        <td><%=person.mobnum%></td>
                        <td><%=person.photo%></td>
                    </tr>
                <%end%>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h5><%=link_to "Veiw Full Details", {controller: :managedb ,action: :details, famid: @fam.famid} %></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now **the `modal` renders properly** but it only has the last `family` in `@fam` variable.

**How can I pass the `family id` as parameter from the modal's link?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it with the first method.
Altered few css properties of `modal`

```
.modal-backdrop {background: none;z-index:-1;}
```

and

```
#myModal {z-index:1;}
```

Now  all the elements in the modal are clickable like a normal bootstrap-modal.